# Cannot read property 'screamId' of undefined(react-redux)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-redux

I am currently working on a social application. I have tried a lot of different methods of passing params(screamId) in regarding but it seems to still be undefined for some reason. Any help is appreciated... code is below

The Home page shows all screams were created.

By calling the action on getScreamsAction function to get all screams.

On Scream component was showed scream card one by one with its screamId.

Home.js

```
const Home = ({ getScreamsAction, data: { screams, loading } }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getScreamsAction();
  }, [getScreamsAction]);

  const scream = screams.map((scream) => (
    <Scream key={scream.screamId} screams={scream} />
  ));

  const recentScream = !loading ? scream : <ScreamSkeleton />;

  return (
    <Grid container spacing={16}>
      <Grid item sm={8} xs={12}>
        {recentScream}
      </Grid>
      <Grid item sm={4} xs={12}>
        <Profile />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

Home.propTypes = {
  getScreamsAction: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  data: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  data: state.data,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = { getScreamsAction };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

action redux

Get data of scream on SET_SCREAMS that dispatch to action

```
const getScreamsAction = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: LOADING_DATA });

  axios
    .get("/screams")
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: SET_SCREAMS,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({
        type: SET_SCREAMS,
        payload: [],
      });
    });
};
```

reducer on redux

```
const dataReducers = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOADING_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
    case SET_SCREAMS:
      return {
        ...state,
        screams: action.payload,
        loading: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
    };
}
```

**The difficulty I have found with the approach:**

[image]

I've tried everything. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

#### It means somewhere you are asking for SOMETHING.screamId

In the code you have shown the only place this happens is `scream.screamId`. Therefore I suggest your next debugging step is to display the screams before that. For example:

```
const Home = ({ getScreamsAction, data: { screams, loading } }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getScreamsAction();
  }, [getScreamsAction]);

  console.log("screams: ", JSON.stringify(screams, null, 2))

  const scream = screams.map((scream) => (
    <Scream key={scream.screamId} screams={scream} />
  ));
```

It would help if you pinpoint the exact numbered line referred to in the TypeError, and show that line of code, because the error may not be coming from the code above - it's just the only place we are seeing a screamId property being accessed, in the code you provided.